# Householder reduction to Hessenberg form

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I've read somewhere that  Hessenberg decomposition is not unique unless the first column of $Q$ in $Q^{T}AQ =H$ is specified. But then, if I am given a matrix $A \in R^{n \times n}$, I can apply the Householder reduction algorithm to reduce $A$ to Hessenberg form $H$ which is the unique output of the algorithm. Then how is that not unique?

Comment: But you may also apply the Hessenberg reduction to $PAP$ where $P=I-2vv^T/v^Tv$ is a Householder reflector. This premultiplication can not be undone by the reflectors of the Hessenberg reduction algorithm. See "bulge chasing methods" in implicitely shifted QR algorithms.

Comment: For those who wonder where the statement for Hessenberg decomposition is not unique presents: Golub, G.H. & Van Loan, C.F. (2013), Matrix Computations, 4-Ed., p. 381.

Answer (score 1):

Every $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ is already in Hessenberg form. If you choose a transformation matrix $Q$ (it can be also orthogonal) and compute

$$B = QAQ^{-1}\text{,}$$

then probably, $A\neq B$ for *some* $Q$s.